# Listview and using graphics

Tags: c#, listview

I have a listview with a top 10 showing me values. I wanted to try and spice it up a tad by showing something like an up arrow graphic for values that are up, a down graphic for a value that is down. Is that something easy to so within the listview and can someone help or guide me through a code to be able to do that??

Thanks

Comment: WinForms and yes there is a listview in C#.

Comment: No, there is no ListView in C#. *WinForms*, however, does have a ListView. It has nothing to do with C#.

Comment: Please add the WinForms Tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, very easy. See the [ListView control MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398790.aspx).

```
<asp:ListView runat="server" ID="ListView1" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1">
  <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" 
          ImageUrl='<%#Eval("UpOrDown") + ".jpg" %>' />
  </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can set [`OwnerDraw`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.ownerdraw.aspx) to `true` and then handle the [`DrawItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawitem.aspx), [`DrawSubItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawsubitem.aspx), [`DrawColumnHeader`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listview.drawcolumnheader.aspx) events.

Note this is assuming you're talking about the WinForms `ListView`.